# Changing of colour depending on $sum

Tags: php

i have a simple php maths script that works really well, it works out a sum that will be shown within a table which displays perfectly.

i am wanting the output to be a different color depending on the final answer

I have simplify the code to try to make this work and then build on it after.

```
<?php

$lhours = 10;
$repaircosts = 20;
$labourpay = 20;
$sum_total = (($lhours * $labourpay) + $repaircosts) ;

function getProperColor($sum_total)

if ($sum_total > 0 && $sum_total <= 0)
return '#00FF00';
else if ($sum_total >= 0 && $sum_total <= 50)
return = '#ffd800';
else if ($sum_total >= 50 && $sum_total <= 120)
return = '#5e7810';
else if ($sum_total >= 121)
return = '#afe214';

print £($sum_total);

?>
```

i have looked at the functions in the php manual and found code snippets on other websites

also i am using Adobe dreamweaver and it gives me syntax errors on the line

```
if ($sum_total > 0 && $sum_total <= 0)
```

also is dreamweaver the best software to use for php for learning purposes as i am new to this?

Thanks in advance

---

Aditional Update

---

Now my code looks like this but it dont mater on the answer its always red

```
<?php
$lhours = 10;
$repaircosts = 20;
$labourpay = 20;
$sum_total = (($lhours * $labourpay) + $repaircosts) ;

function getProperColor($sum_total)
{
    if ($sum_total <= 0)
    return '#00FF00';
    else if ($sum_total >= 0 && $sum_total <= 50)
    return '#ffd800';
    else if ($sum_total >= 50 && $sum_total <= 120)
    return '#5e7810';
    else if ($sum_total >= 121)
    return '#afe214';
}
echo '<font color=getProperColor($sum_total);>'.$sum_total.'</font>';
?>
```

Comment: How can a number be (bigger than 0) and (equal or lower than 0) at the same time?

Comment: $sum can't be greater than 0 *AND* less then or equal to 0. This is your error here: if ($sum_total > 0 && $sum_total <= 0)

Comment: how would i make it a negative?

Comment: Where are you opening and closing your function? `{` and `}` missing

Comment: Do you really have a function called `£`?

Comment: You don't have to make it negative. The first check already makes sure that $sum_total is NOT less than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
   <?php
    $lhours = 10;
    $repaircosts = 20;
    $labourpay = 1;
    $sum_total = (($lhours * $labourpay) + $repaircosts) ;

    echo getProperColor($sum_total);

    function getProperColor($sum_total)
    {
        $finalColor = "#000";//Define a default color
        $outputHtml="<span style='color:";//start the output HTML
        if ($sum_total <= 0)://Note the syntax here
             $finalColor = '#00FF00';
        elseif ($sum_total >= 0 && $sum_total <= 50):
             $finalColor = '#ffd800';
        elseif ($sum_total >= 50 && $sum_total <= 120):
              $finalColor = '#5e7810';
        elseif ($sum_total >= 121):
              $finalColor = '#afe214';
        endif;//end the ifs
      $outputHtml.=$finalColor."'>".$sum_total."</span>";//Append the color and sum to our html
      return $outputHtml;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing code block brackets `{}` and I fixed your logic.

```
function getProperColor($sum_total)
{
   if ($sum_total <= 0)
      return '#00FF00';
   else if ($sum_total <= 50)
      return '#ffd800';
   else if ($sum_total <= 120)
     return '#5e7810';

   return '#afe214';
}
```

Comment: thanks :) i just replaced my code and still getting syntax errors at each return line

Comment: `return '#afe214';`, no `=` sign

Comment: @RickNash lol, I copy/pasted your code but didn't notice you used a `=` sign on the return statements. Remove those as they are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$lhours = 10;
$repaircosts = 20;
$labourpay = 20;
$sum_total = (($lhours * $labourpay) + $repaircosts) ;

function getProperColor($sum_total)
{
    if ($sum_total <= 0)
    return '#00FF00';
    else if ($sum_total >= 0 && $sum_total <= 50)
    return '#ffd800';
    else if ($sum_total >= 50 && $sum_total <= 120)
    return '#5e7810';
    else if ($sum_total >= 121)
    return '#afe214';
}
echo '<font color=getProperColor($sum_total);>'.$sum_total.'</font>';
?>
```

Comment: Can't have $sum_total > 0 AND $sum_total <= 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code.

```
<?php

$lhours = 10;
$repaircosts = 20;
$labourpay = 20;
$sum_total = (($lhours * $labourpay) + $repaircosts) ;

function getProperColor($sum_total)
{
if ($sum_total < 0)
return '#00FF00';
else if ($sum_total > 0 && $sum_total < 50)
return '#ffd800';
else if ($sum_total > 50 && $sum_total < 120)
return '#5e7810';
else if ($sum_total > 120)
return '#afe214';
}
print getProperColor($sum_total);

?>
```

Comment: Can't have `$sum_total > 0` AND `$sum_total <= 0`.